# Locally storing form to set last current form to the new current form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I know the title sounds quite difficult to understand (weird) but here is it's explanation:

Suppose I have 2 forms on my page. A button's click hides a current form and then shows up another. I refresh the page. Now I want the form which was before the refresh the current form to be after the refresh to be current form aswell. I know that it can be done by using `localStorage` but I don't know how. :P

**Code (HTML):**

```
<div class="span5">
    <!-- Row's 2nd Column holding the sign-in/sign-up form -->
    <form action="login.php" method="post" class="form-signin" id="login_frm">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
    <form action="login.php" method="post" class="form-signin hide" id="register_frm">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_register" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:** *Using bootstrap :)*

**JS:**

```
var registerBtn = $("#register_button"); //storing the hyperlink of register in a variable
var i = 0; //click count
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register_button").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast');

            });
            $(this).text('Register');
        } else {
            $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
            });
            $(this).text('Login');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could do this much easier with PHP, why choose local storage?

Comment: @DevlshOne I think he wants to do it at client side. PHP would need to either refresh the page when clicking the button to hide the form, or to get notified via Ajax (probably more code than with `localStorage`).

Comment: So, if the login information is invalid once submitted, then the register form should appear? Is that the way I read this?

Comment: @DevlshOne How I understand it is that there is a separate button to switch between the two forms. The switching is done using jQuery.

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes it right. and DevlshOne, if the register form is wrongly submitted it should appear not hidden and the login form should apper hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here should be a working solution. I've marked new code with a comment.

```
var registerBtn = $("#register_button"); //storing the hyperlink of register in a variable
var i = 0; //click count
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register_button").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast');

            });
            $(this).text('Register');
            localStorage.setItem("form", "login"); // < NEW CODE
        } else {
            $("#login_frm").fadeToggle('fast', function () {
                $("#register_frm").fadeToggle('fast');
            });
            $(this).text('Login');
            localStorage.setItem("form", "register"); // < NEW CODE
        }
    });
    // v NEW CODE v
    if (localStorage.getItem("form") == "register") {
        $("#register_button").click();
    }
    // ^ NEW CODE ^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, although it does not work very well as a jsFiddle because of the page refresh due to the action method. PS. No need for local storage (in the conventional sense), these two variables can just be a couple of data properties of the window itself.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var registerBtn = $("#register_button");
        var rform = $('#register_frm');
        var lform = $('#login_frm');
        lform.show();
        rform.hide();
        var i = 0;
        $("#register_button").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            i++;
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                rform.find('input[name = "username"]').val(window.data('username'));
                rform.find('input[name = "password"]').val(window.data('password'));
                $("#register_frm").fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $("#login_frm").fadeIn('fast');
                });
                $(this).text('Register');
            } else {
                window.data('username', val('rform.find(input[name = "username"]'));
                window.data('password', val('rform.find(input[name = "password"]'));
                $("#login_frm").fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $("#register_frm").fadeIn('fast');
                });
                $(this).text('Login');
            }
        });
    });
```